# How to order a post type with meta_value_num and if meta_value_num does not exist then order by date

Tags: wp-query, meta-query, order

I want to order a list of post on basis of ratings. I have used meta key "wp_ratings" for storing the rating value in wp_postmeta table.
Now I want to sort all posts .
If a post does not contains the meta key , then sort it with date.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'recipe',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'    => 40,
    'orderby'           => array( 'meta_value_num' => 'DESC',  'date' => 'DESC' ),
    'meta_key'          => 'wp_ratings',
);

$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

echo '<pre>';
var_dump( $my_query );
echo '</pre>';
```

It is still showing me only 4 post that has wp_ratings postmeta . But it is not showing me the rest 36 posts.

FYI: I am using WP 4.0.1
I am using this code, but still its not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a space-delimited set of columns to `orderby` argument of WP Query:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'wp_ratings',
    'orderby'  => 'meta_value_num date'
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

You can also pass an array of `key => sort_order` for more granular control, for example:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'wp_ratings',
    'orderby' => array (
                     'meta_value_num' => 'DESC',
                     'date'           => 'ASC'
                 )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Your actual problem seems to be related with the query and not with the order. As a `meta_key` has been set, the query will look for some value for that meta key. Because you want get posts with or without that meta key, you need to specify it in the `meta_query`:

```
$args = array(
    //meta key for orderby
    'meta_key'   => 'wp_ratings',
    //Meta query set to include when meta_key doesn't exist
    'meta_query' => array(
                        'relation' => 'OR',
                        array(
                            'key'     => 'wp_ratings',
                            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
                        ),
                        array(
                            'key'     => 'wp_ratings',
                            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
                        )
                    ),
    'orderby'    => array (
                     'meta_value_num' => 'DESC',
                     'date'           => 'ASC'
                    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: I have modified the question and added the code.
But still its not working.

Comment: The code you have provided in the question is similar to the posted in the answer. It should work but I can not reproduce your problem as you are using conditionals that I can not test: for exmpale, you don't provide information about what `$sort` is or where that var come from, so we can not debug your code nor reproduce the issue. Test the multiple `orderby` without any conditional and it works (it should) your problem is anywhere else but not in the `orderby` agument.

Comment: I have updated my question with a general query which I tested with and it is still not working for me.

Comment: Where are you executing this code? In the front-end?

Comment: Yes. I have added the above code in my functions.php file and var_dump the output.

Comment: I'm not sure but you are changin the meta key from `wp_ratings` to `wp_recipe_avg_ratings` and again to `wp_ratings`. Who knows where the problem is with that changing information.

Comment: See updated answer, you need to include posts when `meta_key` doesn't exist.

Comment: Beat by minutes with that answer.