# WP_Query ordered by meta_value_num doesn't fetch posts without this meta field

Tags: meta-query, order, wp-user-query

I have a custom user query, which should order users by a custom meta field `staff_profile_position`. Users, who don't have a `staff_profile_position` are not fetched with this query:

```
$args = array(
    'role'  => 'my_staff_role',
    'fields' => 'all',
    'meta_key' => 'staff_profile_position',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => 'staff_profile_position',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ),
        array(
            'key'           => 'staff_profile_position',
            'compare'   => 'NOT EXISTS',
        ),
    ),
    'orderby' => array(
        'meta_value_num' => 'ASC',
    ),
);
```

How can I get all users ordered by `staff_profile_position`, if they have, followed by all the others?

The query above follows [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/178241/how-to-order-a-post-type-with-meta-value-num-and-if-meta-value-num-does-not-exis). But still doesn't work and only fetches users that have this meta field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're only getting those users that have that meta_key is because you're include `'meta_key' => '...'` in `$args`.  That limits results to those that have that key, regardless of any clauses you may have in a `meta_query`.  This applies to `WP_Query`, `WP_User_Query` and `WP_Comment_Query`.

Starting in WP 4.2, you can "name" the clauses in a `meta_query` and then use those "names" in the `orderby` clause, see [Query improvements in WP 4.2: ‘orderby’ and ‘meta_query’](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/03/30/query-improvements-in-wp-4-2-orderby-and-meta_query/).  Unfortunately, the code reference and codex entries for `WP_Query` and `WP_User_Query` haven't been updated to reflect this, altho [WP_Meta_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/__construct/) does cover it.

So, you can **ALMOST** get what you're after with the following:

```
$args = array (
    'role'  => 'my_staff_role',
    'fields' => 'all',
    'meta_query' => array (
        'relation' => 'OR',
        'exists' => array (
            'key' => 'staff_profile_position',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
//          'type' => 'NUMERIC',
            ),
        'not_exists' => array (
            'key'     => 'staff_profile_position',
            'compare'   => 'NOT EXISTS',
            ),
        ),
    'orderby' => 'exists not_exists',
    ) ;
```

**Note:** To mimic `'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'` (as you have in your question) you would have to include `'type' => 'NUMERIC'` in the `meta_query` clauses.  However, that causes all of users *without* to sort to the top, instead of the bottom (which is why I have it commented out above).

Thus, if you can live with having those users *with* your meta_key to be ordered by that key treated as a string, rather than a number, then the above will do.

If you can't, then you'll have to do 2 separate queries (one for those users with the meta_key, ordered numerically by that key, and one for those users without the meta_key) and merge the results of those 2 queries.

Comment: Oh good to know. I've read through the Query Improvements docs but didn't find out about this "naming" option. Cheers!